# How to filter a list based on another list's values

Tags: python

For example, I have two lists of the same length:

```
a = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[4,2],[5,6]]
b = [1,2,2,3,1]
```

I want to have a function such that

```
func(a,b,1) = [[1,2],[5,6]]
func(a,b,2) = [[2,2],[3,3]]
func(b,b,2) = [2,2]
```

What the function does is return a list of a's elements, whose corresponding elements of the same index in list b equal to the third argument.

In Matlab I will do something as easy as a(b==1), a(b==2), b(b==2). What is the most efficient way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want this function/filter to do

Comment: It would be useful to actually explain what you want, rather than expect us to deduce it from input/output. Also, what have you tried? SO is not a place to get code written for you.

Comment: Ah I get it, it's: Return the values in the first argument in the positions of the elements in the second argument that are equal the third argument.

Comment: You need to explain what you want func to do? You can't assume we know matlab nor can you assume we can deduce what func does from input/output.

Comment: Sorry guys I assumed the Matlab expression explained it all. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want *very* Matlab-like functionality, you could use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[4,2],[5,6]]
>>> b = [1,2,2,3,1]
>>> a = numpy.array(a)
>>> b = numpy.array(b)
>>> a[b==1]
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
>>> a[b==2]
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
>>> b[b==2]
array([2, 2])
```

Failing that, I'd probably simply use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j == 1]
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
>>> [i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j == 2]
[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> [i for i,j in zip(b,b) if j == 2]
[2, 2]
```

It'd be trivial to wrap this in a function:

```
>>> def func(a,b,x):
...     return [i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j == x]
... 
>>> func(a,b,2)
[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`itertools.compress()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) along with a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) to do this:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    return itertools.compress(a, (x == c for x in b))
```

Note that this will return a generator. If you need a list, wrap it in a `list()` call.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def func(a, b, c):
...     return list(itertools.compress(a, (x == c for x in b)))
... 
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[4,2],[5,6]]
>>> b = [1,2,2,3,1]
>>> func(a, b, 1)
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
>>> func(a, b, 2)
[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> func(b, b, 2)
[2, 2]
```

It's also worth noting this should be nice and fast - `itertools` is designed to be a fast module.

Answer (score 4):

This first finds the indices where `b` equals the target values (`[i for i, x in enumerate(b) if x==c]`), then uses those indices to get the elements you want out of `a`:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    return [a[j] for j in [i for i, x in enumerate(b) if x==c]]

>>> func(a,b,1)
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
>>> func(a,b,2)
[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> func(b,b,2)
[2, 2]
```

Comment: Well done for working that out based on what he gave - it was cryptic at best.

Comment: @Lattyware: The description might not have been clear, but I thought the Matlab code was.

Comment: @Junuxx no need of two for loops, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(a,b,n):
   return [a[i] for i,x in enumerate(b) if x==n]

a = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[4,2],[5,6]]
b = [1,2,2,3,1]
print(func(a,b,1)) #[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
print(func(a,b,2)) #[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
print(func(b,b,2)) #[2, 2]
```